# how to synchronise Linux/Debian machine

Tags: linux, debian

Hi I am using the Linux machine. I am configuring it for the session repication of the tomcat. My requirement is that both the machine must be synchronise with some standard time. May be with some internate time.If any one ans me how to synchronise both the machine?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

setup ntp http://www.debianadmin.com/ntp-server-and-client-configuration-in-debian.html

Answer (score 2):

prefer ntpd over ntpdate since ntpdate is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Use an NTP server and ntpdate is an option:
`ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org`
Run this as a crontab every minute on both servers.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this option is available on Debian. Apologies if not, let me know and I'll delete.

Comment: It's available. I still prefer using an ntp server though, as ntpdate jumps through the time when the clock is wrong while the server adjusts the clock speed until the time is correct. Jumping through the time is bad, especially when it goes backward, as times in log files will be ambiguous and some programs have problems with non-continuous time.